# Undefined function oci_connect() thougn php.ini has extension=php_oci8.dll

Tags: php, oracle10g, xampp

I am trying to connect `xampp` with `oracle 10gexpress edition`. I have changed my `php.ini` fite which has `extension=php_oci8.dll`. But cannot connect. The error is

```
Fatal error: undefined function oci_connect() in ...
```

I have run `phpinfo()`, and my configure command has :

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"
```

I think here is the problem. I can not find out. want a solution .

Comment: Moderator .... Is there any problem? I need help.....

Comment: Hi, how was your issue? I'm encountering the same issue also. Are you able to solve it? Please kindly share if yes. Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone found solution to this problem, I m getting same issue to connect PHP to Oracle 10g. php_oci8_12c.dll was already there in php/ext and comment was removed from .ini. Then I have also downloaded instantclient_10_2 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html and path variable and php.ini (both prod and dev) have been modified to include all extensions. Still it says Call to undefined function oci_connect(); I am working on Windows/IIS environment.